# Change slick slider slides from another component

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, antd, slick.js

I have two separate components. In component A I have some links and in the component B have an slick slider. How can I change the slides with Links onClick event in component A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to manage a `slideIndex` state in the closest common parent component.

Pass down `setSlideIndex` as a prop for the Links component to update the state. The state is passed down to the Slider component and use react-slick's `slickGoTo` function to update the carousel with `useEffect`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";

function Parent() {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <Links onClick={setSlideIndex} />
      <Slider slideIndex={slideIndex} />
    </>
  );
}

function Links({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => onClick(0)}>Show Slide 1</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => onClick(1)}>Show Slide 2</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => onClick(2)}>Show Slide 3</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => onClick(3)}>Show Slide 4</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}

function Slider({ slideIndex }) {
  const slider = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    slider.current.slickGoTo(slideIndex);
  }, [slideIndex]);

  return (
    <Carousel ref={slider}>
      <div>Slide 1</div>
      <div>Slide 2</div>
      <div>Slide 3</div>
      <div>Slide 4</div>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
Slider.defaultProps = {
  slideIndex: 0
};
```

Comment: With this solution the animation not works and just render the element :(

Comment: I may have misunderstood. I thought you meant you wanted to render a different slider for each link. Are you saying you have 1 slider and want to switch to a different slide when you click a link?

Comment: Based on my new understanding, I have fixed the example. Let me know if this solves your issue!

Comment: Works with a little change, In antd we should add slider.current.slick.slickGoTo(slideIndex). Thanks alot.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help!

Comment: how can i do this in a Class Component? @FatemehQasemkhani